# Strange Date() hour increment on March 12 2017

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime

When I create a new Date() object for March 12, 2017, the hour 2am reads as 3am when I call getHours(). It should read 2am as I originally specified. Am I doing something wrong? Here is my code. DateB is where i'm having problems.

```
console.log("\nDate A:");
DateA = new Date("March 12 2017 01:00:00");
console.log("H: "+DateA.getHours());
console.log("M: "+DateA.getMinutes());
console.log("S: "+DateA.getSeconds());
console.log("D: "+DateA.getDate());
console.log("M: "+DateA.getMonth());
console.log("Y: "+DateA.getFullYear());
/*
    Date A:
    H: 1
    M: 0
    S: 0
    D: 12
    M: 2
    Y: 2017
*/

//PROBLEM DATE:
console.log("\nDate B:");
DateA = new Date("March 12 2017 02:00:00");
console.log("H: "+DateA.getHours());
console.log("M: "+DateA.getMinutes());
console.log("S: "+DateA.getSeconds());
console.log("D: "+DateA.getDate());
console.log("M: "+DateA.getMonth());
console.log("Y: "+DateA.getFullYear());
/*
    Date B:
    H: 3
    M: 0
    S: 0
    D: 12
    M: 2
    Y: 2017 
*/

console.log("\nDate C:");
DateA = new Date("March 12 2017 03:00:00");
console.log("H: "+DateA.getHours());
console.log("M: "+DateA.getMinutes());
console.log("S: "+DateA.getSeconds());
console.log("D: "+DateA.getDate());
console.log("M: "+DateA.getMonth());
console.log("Y: "+DateA.getFullYear());
/*
    Date C:
    H: 3
    M: 0
    S: 0
    D: 12
    M: 2 
    Y: 2017
*/
```

Comment: Do you need to use a string when creating the date? There are many other alternatives.

Comment: March 12 2017 is where clocks may change due to Daylight Saving Time depending on your region

Comment: I need to initialize a Date object from a past timestamp string. I tried using setHours() and it produces the same result. 2am is skipped and reads as 3am.

Comment: British summer time? Seems to return OK here https://jsfiddle.net/w1zxkofv/

Comment: Yup, it has to be daylight savings time. Thanks! I'm in PST time.

Comment: Creating a date for exactly the changeover time is fraught. Some implementations will add or subtract the DST offset exactly on the time, others will wait for the next millisecond, and some get the changeover period wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On March 12th,2017 Dailight Saving time began (https://www.wincalendar.com/Calendar/Date/March-12-2017) so at 2 am the clocks where advanced to 3am. 2am never existed.